# How to use external usb camera on android device with camera lib

Tags: flutter, camera

I'm developing a Flutter APP for my android PAD, it needs accessing external usb camera, I'm using the camera lib, it's version is ^0.10.5+3. I have check the source code, it seems to support the external USB camera. So I tried to change initialCameraLensDirection to CameraLensDirection.external, but it doesnot work, anything wrong? or this lib doesn't support external usb camera.